# Any reason why my Vector is losing its data?

Tags: java, vector, iterator

My current goal here is to add objects to a vector in order to be accessed by an iterator in another class created by me (for this project I am not allowed to use Java's iterator). My iterator function is supposed to return a specific object inside the vector. Instead, the iterator is reporting null values within the vector. After debugging, the problem is after objects are added on startup the objects disappear. Passing the vector into the iterator class doesn't solve the issue. I've tried using an array list instead of a vector with no luck.

```
public void init() { //where im doing the adding
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cyborg = new Player(ColorUtil.rgb(42, 194, 225), 50, 46.0, baseLocations[0], 40, 100, 100, 0, 50, true);
        go.add((Player) cyborg);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        NPC = new NPC(ColorUtil.rgb(42, 194, 225), 50, 46.0, baseLocations[0], 40, 100, 100, 0, 50, currStrat);
        go.add((NPC) NPC);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        drone = new Drone(ColorUtil.rgb(82, 95, 81), r.nextInt(50), 10.0,
                new Point(r.nextFloat() * 1000, r.nextFloat() * 1000), r.nextInt(50));
        go.add(drone);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        base = new Base(ColorUtil.rgb(169, 235, 0), baseSequence++, baseLocations[i], 10);
        go.add((Fixed) base);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        eStation = new eStation(ColorUtil.rgb(100, 85, 85), new Point(r.nextFloat() * 1000, r.nextFloat() * 1000),
                r.nextInt(50), 100);
        go.add((Fixed) eStation);

    }



public class GameCollection implements ICollection {

private Vector<GameObject> gameCollection;

public GameCollection() {
    gameCollection = new Vector<GameObject>(); //the vector im having problems with
    System.out.println(gameCollection.toString()); //Test to check if objects in game collection array. Prints null values after startup
}

public IIterator getIterator() {

    GameCollectionIterator gameItr = new GameCollectionIterator(gameCollection);
            return gameItr;


}

public void add(GameObject o) {
    gameCollection.addElement(o);
    //System.out.println(super.toString());
}



public Object elementAt(int location) {
    if(location < gameCollection.size()) {
        return (Object) gameCollection.indexOf(location);
    }

     throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(location);

}
public void remove(GameObject o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gameCollection.remove(gameCollection.indexOf(o));
}




private class GameCollectionIterator implements IIterator{
    private int currIndex = 0;

    private Vector <GameObject> game = new Vector <GameObject>();

    public GameCollectionIterator(Vector<GameObject> g) {
        game = g;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(game.size() <= 0){
            System.out.println("First case");
            return false;

        }
        if(currIndex == game.size() -1){
            System.out.println("Second case");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNext() {
        currIndex++;
        return(game.indexOf(currIndex));
    }





    @Override
    public void remove() {
        game.remove(currIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. If you still need help, create a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and run ourselves and see the same behavior you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems with your iterator here:

```
@Override
public Object getNext() {
    currIndex++; // (1)
    return(game.indexOf(currIndex)); // (2)
}
```

1. `currIndex++;` - you increment index before getting the element from the vector, so you basically always skip the first element (with index 0).
2. `game.indexOf(currIndex)` - `indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). You have to use `get` method instead, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get-int-).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we can't actually see what is going on because you haven't provided an kind of "driver" so that we can understand *how* these classes are being used.

However, I suspect that the problem is that your `GameCollectionIterator` is incorrect.  It has a number of problems, including:

1. The `next` method is assuming that there is a next element.  It is not checking.  (OK, we don't know what the `IIterator` contract says should happen, but this is very suspicious.)
2. As @rxn1d also notes, `next` increments `currIndex` (which starts as zero) before using it.  That means that the iterator will skip the first element under most circumstances.
3. @rxn1d is also correct about `return(game.indexOf(currIndex));`.  That statement will actually:

   - autobox `currIndex` to an `Integer`
   - attempt to find the `Integer` in the list,
   - fail ... giving the `int` value `-1`, and
   - autobox and return *that*<sup>1</sup>.
4. There is nothing in the iterator implementation to detect the case of elements being added or removed while iterating.  When you remove any object, the remaining objects beyond the removal point will have their positions changed.  But you are not adjusting `currIndex` for this.  Thus a removal is liable to cause objects to be skipped.
5. The iterator will not be thread-safe.  (Not clear if this matters ...)

Note that the standard (non-concurrent) implementations of `java.util.Collection` will detect a concurrent modification and throw an exception *precisely* to avoid problems like 4.

---

Some other things that should be corrected.

- You should get rid of superfluous blank lines and autogenerated comments<sup>2</sup> before you as other people to read your code.
- I don't understand why you are using your own `IIterator` and `ICollection` interfaces ... or what they actually mean.  (Where are the declarations?  Where are the javadocs?)
- Your `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(location);` is throwing the wrong exception.  Your collection is not an array.
- `eStation` is a bad class name.  Class names shout **always** start with an uppercase letter.  Then you compound this by declaring a variable with exactly the same name as its class.
- Assuming that `eStation` is a subtype of `GameObject`, the type cast in `go.add((Fixed) eStation);` is unnecessary.  Other examples of this.

---

<sup>1 - I am surprised that you did not notice that `next` was returning `Integer` objects.  Or if you did, that you didn't think it was significant enough to mention.</sup>

<sup>2 - You should always do this before showing your code to other people and ask them to read it.  Treat us like you would treat your future co-workers.</sup>